# Is a[i] really the same as *(a + i) in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum2d(int row, int col, int p[row][col]);
int main(void)
{
    int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    printf("%d\n", sum2d(2, 3, a));


    return 0;
}
int sum2d(int row, int col, int p[row][col])
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            total += (*(p + i))[j];
    return total;
}
```

Look at the above code.  It works perfectly.

However, after I changed **p[row]** into ***(p + row)**,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum2d(int row, int col, int (*(p + row))[col]);
int main(void)
{
    int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

    printf("%d\n", sum2d(2, 3, a));


    return 0;
}
int sum2d(int row, int col, int (*(p + row))[col])
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            total += (*(p + i))[j];
    return total;
}
```

it can't be compiled and displays the following error message :

```
test.c:2:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘+’ token
 int sum2d(int row, int col, int (*(p + row))[col]);
                                      ^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sum2d’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  printf("%d\n", sum2d(2, 3, a));
  ^
test.c: At top level:
test.c:12:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘+’ token
 int sum2d(int row, int col, int (*(p + row))[col])
```

At my current level, I barely understand it.

In C, I thought **a[i]** = ***(a + i)** .

Why is my code not correct ?

Comment: You mix up 3 different terms. An array variable declaration is different from an function parameter declaration which is different from an expression using arrays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ***expression*** `a[i]` is equal to the ***expression*** `*(a + i)`. Using the pointer-arithmetic syntax in declarations is invalid.

Comment: ...and `*(a + i)` makes `a[i] == i[a]`!

Comment: @haccks `puts( &false["not this crap again..."] );`

Comment: @Lundin; Hehe. BTW, this will certainly give a compile error :)

Comment: @haccks Not if you include stdio.h and stdbool.h. Perfectly valid C :)

Answer (score 6):

The syntax is correct when the `[]` is used as the postfix array subscription operator, not as an array declarator.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.1

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
>   is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th
>   element of `E1` (counting from zero).